# Trying to dual boot - getting error failing to unmount /cdrom

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, but Ubiquity doesn't find a 25GB FAT32 partition when I am trying to install it from a USB stick.

My original install for Windows 10 was done with drives formatted in NTFS because FAT32 and exFAT wouldn't boot

I do have the drive with that partition as a priority for boot option 1 on a separate drive.

Boot option 1 is my USB with Ubuntu installed.

I have turned off fast boot and hibernation in Windows.

Right now I am failing to unmount `/cdrom` and make a connection to dbus-daemon

I just don't have the skills to get Ubuntu to install right now.

[image]

[image]

Updated with a picture of the screen I have been stuck on for 4 hours. This is the loop. If there is a way to access a CLI from here, I don't know how to access it.

Live USB does not support Ubuntu 20.04.

Loading with the NTFS format doesn't work. Still in a [FAILED], [DEPEND], [OK] loop. besides see systemct1 status systemd-journal.service no other errors seem to be showing up.

So I ran the commands in the GRUB terminal and it kicked out an error. Although if I am reading it correctly, I am missing the device folder in my install. Also Windows won't turn off. I swear Microsoft is just trying to brick this machine.

Motherboard: Asus Crosshair Hero 8 (WiFi)

Comment: Should I place Grub2 inside the FAT32 partition that I made, even though Rufus installs GRUB2 into the USB drive?

Comment: Before making any changes. let's see what you have. Please boot from the LiveUSB you made for installation of Ubuntu, open a terminal, and run _sudo lshw -short -C disk ; lsblk | grep -v  loop  ; df -h | grep -v loop ; sudo blkid ; dmesg | grep '/dev/sd'   ; dmesg | grep '/dev/nvm'_ Highlight the resulting text then copy it with Ctrl-Shift-C . Open Firefox,, come back here, click [edit], and paste the resulting text into your question, so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All your facts should go in the Question w/ [edit]

Comment: I can't get why are you installing Ubuntu to `fat32`. It's not possible.

Comment: In Windows you need to turn fast start up/hibernation off. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
 Many systems need UEFI update & if SSD, SSD firmware update. What brand/model system?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  & Swap not now requires as file used: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read some HowTo's on installing Ubuntu for dual boot. Google or search here on AU.

Download the relevant Ubuntu ISO.

- Use a recommended tool to "burn it" to a USB stick or DVD
- Then, from windows, make sure that the diskspace you want to use for Ubuntu is free

  - Is it a part of your current Windows drives (C: D: or so),shrink that partition/filesystem.
  - Is it a empty partition, delete it (have your stuff backed up in case you delete something you later need.
- Then boot on the media you created, and select install beside Windows,and follow descriptions.

Comment: I appreciate the help, however I followed most of the how to (except the verification process) and am still unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue with CDROM error during installation. I have Dell laptop without cdrom but probably the issue was made by my backup directory to the same partition as bootable system, so now i skip this.

helped the re-create usb disk by rufus (https://rufus.ie/en/) and mark checkbox "Add patch for old BIOS" and also setup this option in my bios.

And for sure before installation I commented cdrom source from /etc/apt/source.list and in "Software & Update" I turned off all checkbox with CDROM through all tabs through, but weird was twice the same checkbox in scroll field on first tab, moreover first time was present only one, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a bootable hdd partition to boot Ubuntu,then make sure that it's on a different drive from the one you wish to install the OS on to avoid this error.